# While using ord([a word]) I get an issue saying that it is a number

Tags: python

I am trying to turn a word entered by the user, into numbers. I enter a word, but I get the following error:

```
step1 = ord(letter)
```

> TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found

This is my code (I cut out some things before this that were not necessary):

```
phrase = str(input("Enter sentence"))
list = []
for letter in phrase:
    list.append(letter)
maxlist = len(list)
convert = True
while convert == True :
    for letter in list :
        counter = 0
        while counter < maxlist :
            step1 = ord(letter)
            list[0 + counter] = step1
            counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: What is `secondlen`?

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name. It will overwrite the built in type. To get a word in to a list as individual letters all you need to do is `word = list(phrase)`

Comment: @IanAuld that isn't the issue here though. But it is something to point out.

Comment: Add a `print(letter)` before you call `ord()` and see what is getting passed in.

Comment: I edited it, secondlen is now maxlist

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Now, that I added print(letter) before the ord(), I've seen some problems but I dont really know the cause... Shall I show my whole program?

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the values in the list with integers:

```
step1 = ord(letter)
list[0 + counter] = step1
```

Your *next `while` loop iteration* is going to use those integers instead of the letters.

Other notes:

- Don't use `list` as a variable name, you are masking the `list` built-in.
- Converting a string to a list of characters is as simple as using the built-in you masked:

  ```
  characters = list(phrase)
  ```
- Don't use `== True`; `while` and `if` are already testing for true values, you are redundantly checking for that possibility, turning `True` into `True`.
- Converting a sentence into integers is as simple as:

  ```
  phrase = str(input("Enter sentence"))
  converted = [ord(character) for character in phrase]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of this line of code:

`list[0 + counter] = step1`

This is assigning the integer to value inside list, on which then `ord(letter)` is getting called because of `while` loop, giving you the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
phrase = 'asdfsafdsafasdf'
list = []
for letter in phrase:
    list.append(letter)
maxlist = len(list)
print '%r' % list 
convert = True
while convert == True :
    for letter in list :
        counter = 0
        while counter < maxlist :
            print "%r" % letter
            step1 = ord(letter)
            list[0 + counter] = step1
            counter = counter + 1
```

The above code prints:
['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 's', 'a', 'f', 'd', 's', 'a', 'f', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f']
'a'
'a'
'a'
'a'
'a'
'a'
'a'
'a'
'a'
'a'
97

```
 File "/ob/proj/kwtool/kwtool.py", line 459, in <module>
   x()
 File "/ob/proj/kwtool/kwtool.py", line 453, in x
   step1 = ord(letter)
 TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

So there are a few issues here.  The specific reason you are getting the error, is that the second to last line is assigning an int INTO the list array that you are reading letters out of it.  Some thoughts about the code:

```
-- So change list[0 + counter]=step1  to be some other output variable.
-- You have a double loop, but I cannot tell if that is what you intended
-- convert==True will always be true, is it is never changed.
-- you should not use 'list' as a variable name, since you are shadowing the 
   built in 'list' class.
```